# How to keep a key pressed on Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing automatic tests with Selenium Webdriver, and I need to select this [5 boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TytOs.png), but only works while I keep Ctrl pressed, I've already tried this 2 ways:

```
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    driver.findElement(By.id("2")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("3")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("4")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("5")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("6")).click();
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

and

```
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    driver.findElement(By.id("2")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("3")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("4")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("5")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("6")).click();
    action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

But none of them worked, by the time that "Ter" (id 3) is selected, the "Seg" (id 2) is unselected, and so on.
Is there another way to do it? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to click on the 5 buttons that are marked in the photo, the problem is that when I click on one, the other is unchecked, I can't just send 5 click commands. On this site, the only ways to select the 5 buttons, is either by holding ctrl and clicking each one, or by dragging the mouse from the first button to the last. I believe it is easier using ctrl because of these keydown / keyup and keypress / keyrelease functions, but as I said earlier, I tested these two ways that I showed and both did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to use the Action class completely.

Instead of using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("2")).click();
```

so on..

Use

```
moveToElement(toElement)
```

and try to Moves the mouse to the middle of the element.

**Code:**

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("2"))).click();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("3"))).click();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("4"))).click();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("5"))).click();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("6"))).click();
action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

*Note: If possible please share the web link or HTML code for better understanding.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not the way I wanted it, but it worked:

```
WebElement elementoBase = driver.findElement(By.id("2"));
WebElement elementoAlvo = driver.findElement(By.id("6"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(elementoBase).moveToElement(elementoAlvo).release().build().perform();
```